# How to detect when a React Native app is opened?

Tags: react-native

My React Native app wants to synchronize its local data with an API when the user opens the app. This should happen whenever the user returns to the app, not just when it first starts. Essentially, what I would like is the equivalent of AppDelegate's `applicationDidBecomeActive` callback, so that I can run synchronization code there. Obviously, I would like to do this in React Native instead.

As far as I can tell, the `componentWillMount` / `componentDidMount` callbacks on the root component only run when the app is initially loaded, not after the user leaves the app and comes back later (without explicitly quitting the app).

I thought that the `AppState` API would provide this functionality, but its `change` listeners don't fire in this case, either.

This seems like obvious functionality to have, so I must be missing something glaringly obvious. Help!

Comment: I'm currently using react-native 0.26.3 and `AppState` works as expected for both iOS and Android so it seems that `AppStateIOS` is no longer needed.

Comment: Yes. It appears that this was fixed in a recent version of React Native.

Comment: I have used appstate. It works with simulator but event doesn't get fired when using real ios device.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

I fixed this by using the `AppStateIOS` API instead of `AppState`. The later works as expected on iOS devices: when the app goes to the background the `"change"` event fires, and again when it comes back to the foreground. The `AppState` API doesn't seem to fire the `"change"` event at all on an iOS device, as of React Native v0.18, as far as I can tell. The project's conventions suggest that `AppState` should be a cross-platform wrapper around `AppStateIOS`, but that doesn't seem to be the case here.

The following example should demonstrate the issue:

```js
React.createClass({

  componentDidMount() {
    AppStateIOS.addEventListener('change', state =>
      console.log('AppStateIOS changed to', state)
    )

    AppState.addEventListener('change', state =>
      console.log('AppState changed to', state)
    )
  },

  render() {
    return <View/>
  }

})
```

When this component is mounted into a React Native app, you will see "AppStateIOS changed to ..." when closing and opening the app. You will *never* see "AppState changed to ..." as far as I'm aware.

**Update**

It appears that this was fixed in React Native recently (as of v26). You can now use `AppState` as advertised on iOS and Android.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that you're missing something. This functionality is just not provided by react-native out of the box. Maybe the idea was to simplify, since for most apps it's enough to perform data sync when the app returns to foreground.

You can either create your own native module which provides this functionality or you can go with a simple (sort of hacky?) solution:

In your AppDelegate save a reference to the react root view:

```js
@interface AppDelegate()
@property (nonatomic, strong) RCTRootView *rootView;
@end
```

When initializing the view, set your property and use it:

```js
self.rootView = [[RCTRootView alloc] initWithBundleURL:jsCodeLocation
                                            moduleName:@"MyApp"
                                     initialProperties:nil
                                         launchOptions:launchOptions];
```

Now implement the AppDelegate methods for handling the active state like you would do in your iOS apps and pass the information as props:

```js
-(void)onAppActiveStateChanged:(BOOL)appBecameActive
{
  NSMutableDictionary *newProps = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
  if (self.rootView.appProperties != nil) {
    [newProps addEntriesFromDictionary:self.rootView.appProperties];
  }
  newProps[@"appDidBecomeActive"] = @(appBecameActive);
  self.rootView.appProperties = newProps;
}

- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
  [self onAppActiveStateChanged:NO];
}

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
  [self onAppActiveStateChanged:YES];
}
```

On the JavaScript side, do whatever you need when the props change:

```js
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
  if (nextProps.appDidBecomeActive) {
    alert('app did become active');
  }
}
```

I'm not sure if this is the best approach, but it's supposed to work...

Answer (score 0):

I think you answered the question your self already. Why don't you use a combination of componentWillMount and AppState -> 'change'? That should cover all cases. I use this for syncing my app via CodePush.

Comment: Unfortunately, as far as I can tell, `AppState -> 'change'` doesn't fire at all when your app is opened or closed by the user. So I can only detect when the app is first started.

Comment: Hm. In my experience it does. I have AppStateIOS.addEventListener('change', this.onAppStateChange); in the componentDidMount method of my root component. And it fires every time I go to home screen or come back.

Comment: OK. Thanks for following up! I will try that again and report back.

Comment: You mentioning `AppStateIOS` here helped me fix the issue. I was using `AppState` under the assumption that this was a cross-platform wrapper around `AppStateIOS`. However, it doesn't seem to work as advertised.

Comment: I have used appstate. It works with simulator but event doesn't get fired when using real ios device.